# Clear jQuery placeholder on submit

Tags: jquery, html, placeholder

I use jQuery to simulate the HTML5 placeholder function:

```
// placeholder code
$(function() {
    $('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
      var input = $(this);
      if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
        input.val('');
        input.removeClass('placeholder');
      }
    }).blur(function() {
      var input = $(this);
      if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
        input.addClass('placeholder');
        input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
      }
    }).blur().parents('form').submit(function() {
      $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
          input.val('');
        }
      })
    });
});
```

When I now submit the form without changing the placeholders, it uses the placeholders as values.

Can you tell me how to remove all values / placeholders from the textfields when clicking on the submit button? I have seen some solutions here, but it didn't work with the placeholder attribute.

Here is one of my textfield:

```
<input class="frmInputLong" name="inptName" type="text" value="" placeholder="Peter Smith">
```

Here is my form definition:

```
<form id="frmBook" method="post" action="doSomething" >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either execute the submit using jQuery's [`.submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) or add [`.click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handler to the submit button. Inside the function you can do something along the lines of:

```
$("input").attr("placeholder", "");
```

This sets the value of the attribute "placeholder" to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

This should clear all placeholders right before submit unless filled with an actual value

```
$("form:has(.placeholder)").live("submit", function(e){
  $(this).find(".placeholder").val("");
});
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. Is "form" the name of the form?

Comment: no, form is any `form` element, the total selector actually means `any form element that has a child with a 'placeholder' class`

Comment: Seems like it is triggered, but it doesn't clear my input field by using $(this).find(".placeholder").val(""); -- any suggestion?